# How to create a form for each entry/record in a table in Microsoft Access 2013?

Tags: sql, ms-access, database-design, macros, relational-database

I have a table in MS Access 2013 with 217 records in. I would like to create a form for each of these, but is there a way to do this without designing each one manually?

My overall goal is to have a table with a list of sites and in another field what Trust they belong to, and when I click on the name of the Trust I am taken to a form with all the information about that Trust.

Thank you in advance!

Jenna

Comment: I have tried using macros and running queries but to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forms are visual representation of tables. With single forms, each record is displayed on each navigable page. Plus, single forms can have subforms. With continuous forms (multiple item forms) or datasheets, multiple records are displayed on a scrollable page.

You don't need to create a new form for each record but use same form that is filtered to a specific record using the [DoCmd.OpenForm](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff820845.aspx) method's where argument. In your example, behind the button that opens other form, filter the opening form filtered to that particular trust:

VBA route

```
DoCmd.OpenForm "OpeningFormName",  acNormal,  , "TrustID=" & Forms!MainFormName!TrustID"
```

Macro route

```
Action: OpenForm  (search drop down)
Form Name: OpeningFormName (search drop down)
Filter: [leave blank]
Where Condition =: TrustID=Forms!MainFormName!TrustID
Data Mode: [leave blank]
Window Mode: [leave default of Normal]
```

Comment: Thank you for the response Parfait. What you have said makes sense however I can't seem to implement it. The only place where I can type your code is when I go to "Build Event" for a button on a form. It then asks me to chose an Action (OpenForm) Form Name, View, Filter Name and Where Condition. I put your code under Filter Name as it won't accept it under the Where Condition. Sadly it's not working. I apologise in advance as I am very new to all of this. Thank you!

Comment: You are on the macro builder setup. My code is for VBA (code builder option). But see my edit above. Basically, under the event tab of your new button on the main form in the `On Click` option, there are three builder options, two of which I show above (both are equivalent triggers). For Code builder, you place the above VBA line in the pop up IDE window where cursor is positioned.

Comment: Once again thank you for your answers. I think you misunderstand me. I want to create a link in a table to go to a form. For example:

**Site Name**          Aberdeen Hospital      Cardiff Hospital
**Trust**                  Scotland NHS Trust     Wales NHS Trust

Then I want to be able to click on the name of the trust and for that to take me to a form with the details of that trust. If that is possible?

Comment: Sure is, Jenna. But tables don't have the user interface as forms, specifically no trigger events. Consider a [multiple item form](https://support.office.com/en-za/article/Create-a-form-by-using-the-Multiple-Items-tool-881524d6-ef67-46e8-a205-2a05b7ec380b) which have rows structured like tables. Then in the trust field, have an On Click or Double Click event (same event building process as button) that opens a filtered (by TrustID) Trust (single item) form with all Trust details.